# Appropriate USB enclosure to use with an Ultra ATA drive

Tags: hard-drive, usb, macbook, compatibility, enclosures

I have a friend with a broken iBook, but we wish to recover the hard disk. I haven't seen the drive itself, however the spec lists it as an "Ultra ATA drive". Could you please advise if this is 100% compatible with any standard USB IDE 2.5inch enclosure?

**Full spec:**

*iBook 12" 1GHz(AP) 256MB DDR266 SDRAM built-in Keyboard/Mac OS X Bluetooth Module 40GB Ultra ATA drive Combo (DVD-ROM/CD-RW).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ultra ATA" is "standard IDE" so yes, it should be 100% compatible with any modern USB-to-IDE adapter or enclosure.

See Wikipedia's [Parallel ATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA) article for the full history. IDE (Integrated Drive Electronics) was developed by Western Digital, and evolved into the AT Attachment Interface (ATA/ATAPI).  Most "IDE" drives you'll see nowadays are actually "EIDE" drives (Enhanced IDE) -- this just means they meet the specs of some version of ATA/ATAPI, usually between **ATA-2** and **ATA-6**.

Note Wikipedia's [ATA standards table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_ATA#ATA_standards_versions.2C_transfer_rates.2C_and_features):

- **pre-ATA** was also known as **IDE**
- **ATA-1** aka **ATA, IDE**
- **ATA-2** aka **EIDE, Fast ATA, Fast IDE, Ultra ATA**
- **ATA-3** (ditto)
- **ATA/ATAPI-4** aka **ATA-4, Ultra ATA/33**
- **ATA/ATAPI-5** aka **ATA-5, Ultra ATA/66**
- **ATA/ATAPI-6** aka **ATA-6, Ultra ATA/100**
- **ATA/ATAPI-7** aka **SATA/150, SATA 1.0, Ultra ATA/133**

Check the drive's label for one of the above standards, then make sure the USB enclosure you're considering supports that level.  They are backwards-compatible, so if you don't get exact matches, the slowest speed will be used.  (Eg, if you have an ATA-2 drive and an ATA-6 enclosure, it will only use ATA-2 speeds.  Since this is a USB enclosure, this limitation won't matter much.)